# Firefox addon: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, manifest.json

I'm working on a Firefox extension, trying to fetch data from an API (`MapQuest`). At first the API was working fine but suddenly, I started getting the error above `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`, those are the manifest and script codes:

**manifest**

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Distance",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "distance between cities",

  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/Prise_en_charge_OM.aspx"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**script**

```js
if (window.location.href.includes("/Prise_en_charge_OM.aspx")) {
  var apiKey = "<API-KEY>";
  const tableElement = document.getElementById(
    "ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_grv_villes"
  );

  // Load table data from localStorage if available
  const storedTable = retrieveTable();
  if (storedTable) {
    console.log("Table data retrieved from localStorage.");
    tableElement.outerHTML = storedTable;
  }

  const el_form = document.getElementById("form1");
  el_form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    if (
      e.submitter.id ===
      "ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_btn_ajouterjours"
    ) {
      const data = retrieveFromTable(tableElement);
      updateTableWithDistance(tableElement, data);
      storeTable(tableElement.outerHTML);
    }
  });
}

function storeTable(tbl) {
  localStorage.setItem("tbl", tbl);
}

function retrieveTable() {
  return localStorage.getItem("tbl");
}

async function retrieveFromTable(table) {
  const storedData = retrieveDistance() || [];
  const from = table.rows[1].cells[1].textContent;
  const data = [];

  for (let row = 2; row < table.rows.length; row++) {
    const to = table.rows[row].cells[1].textContent;
    const existingDist = storedData.find(
      (dist) => dist.from === from && dist.to === to
    );

    if (existingDist) {
      data.push(existingDist);
    } else {
      const resp = await calculateDrivingDistances(from, to);
      console.log(resp);
      const newDist = { from, to, distance: resp };
      data.push(newDist);
      storedData.push(newDist);
      storeDistance(storedData);
    }
  }

  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

function updateTableWithDistance(table, data) {
  if (table.rows.length > 0) {
    const headerRow = table.rows[0];
    const newHeaderCell = document.createElement("th");
    newHeaderCell.textContent = "Distance";
    headerRow.appendChild(newHeaderCell);

    for (let row = 1; row < table.rows.length; row++) {
      const dataRow = table.rows[row];
      const to = dataRow.cells[1].textContent;
      console.log(data);
      //let distObj = data.find((dist) => dist.to === to);
      let distObj;
      data.then((resp) => {
        distObj = resp.find((dist) => dist.to === to);
        console.log(distObj);
        if (distObj) {
          const newDataCell = document.createElement("td");
          newDataCell.textContent = distObj.distance;
          dataRow.appendChild(newDataCell);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

function storeDistance(data) {
  localStorage.setItem("distances", JSON.stringify(data));
}

function retrieveDistance() {
  const val = localStorage.getItem("distances");
  return val ? JSON.parse(val) : [];
}

async function calculateDrivingDistances(city1, city2) {
  const url = `https://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=${apiKey}&from=${encodeURIComponent(
    city1
  )}&to=${encodeURIComponent(city2)}&unit=k`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    console.log("status: ", response.status);

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(
        `Network response was not ok, status: ${response.status}`
      );
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.route && data.route.distance) {
      const distanceKm = data.route.distance;
      return distanceKm;
    } else {
      console.log("API Error: No distance data in response");
      return 0;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in calculateDrivingDistances:", error);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I'm kind new to APIs, so I'll be glad if you guys can guide me through the problem above and provide simple to understand answers
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this was the problem [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Anw.png), it should have been allowed (like in the picture)

Just go to extensions > gear icon > Manage Extension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).